# Making string as switch case

Tags: java, string, multithreading, switch-statement

In switch case there is an error -> RUNNING, ABORTED and READY cannot be resolved to a variables. What can i do to make it work? Tried enum but it really isn't working.

Main class which i cannot edit:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
StringTask task = new StringTask("A", 70000);
System.out.println("Task " + task.getState());
task.start();
if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("abort")) { 

/*<- code that interrupts task after 1 sec and start a new thread
*/
}
while (!task.isDone()) {
  Thread.sleep(500);
  switch(task.getState()) {
  //error  case RUNNING: System.out.print("R."); break;
  //error  case ABORTED: System.out.println(" ... aborted."); break;
  //error  case READY: System.out.println(" ... ready."); break;
    default: System.out.println("unknown state");
  }

}
System.out.println("Task " + task.getState());
System.out.println(task.getResult().length());
}
}
```

StringTask class:

```
public class StringTask implements Runnable {
String string;
String result = "";
String status = "";
int x;
boolean end = false;
boolean done = false;

public StringTask(String string, int x) {
    this.string = string;
    this.x = x;
    this.status = "CREATED";

}

public void start() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public void run() {
    this.status = "RUNNING";
    synchronized (this.result) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                result += string;
            }
            this.status = "READY";
            this.done = true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            this.status = "ABORTED";
            this.done = false;
        }
    }
}

public void abort() {
    this.end = true;
    this.done = true;
    this.status = "ABORTED";
    Thread.interrupted();
}

public StringTask() {
    this.status = "ABORTED";
}

public String getState() {
    return this.status;
}

public boolean isDone() {
    return this.done;
}

public String getResult() {
    return this.result;
}
}
```

Comment: You'd do better if you define the statuses as an `enum` than as strings. In any case, if you want to switch on strings, take a look at this [guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html).

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that you're not allowed to edit the main class.  To ameliorate your issue, you'll have to make an `enum` to store the status:

```
public enum Status {
    RUNNING, ABORTED, READY
}
```

After changing `StringTask#getState` to return `Status`, you can use your switch statement:

```
switch (task.getState()) {
    case RUNNING:
        System.out.print("R.");
        break;
    case ABORTED: 
        System.out.println(" ... aborted.");
        break;
    case READY:
        System.out.println(" ... ready.");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("unknown state");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `String`s in `switch` case?

`"RUNNING"` instead of `RUNNING` etc?

Comment: Then you need to Use an `Enum` to hold the state.

Answer (score -1):

It seems your assignment is to get the main class to work with `Enum`, to do this you have to change the `StringTask` class. Change the type of **status** to `State`

```
    State status;

    public StringTask(String string, int x) {
        this.string = string;
        this.x = x;
        this.status = State.CREATED;

    }
   ...

    public State getState() {
        return this.status;
    }

    ...

     enum State {
       RUNNING, ABORTED, READY
      }
```

Then your switch should work fine

```
  switch(task.getState()) {
    case RUNNING: 
         System.out.print("R."); 
         break;
    case ABORTED: 
         System.out.println(" ... aborted."); 
         break;
    case READY: 
         System.out.println(" ... ready."); 
         break;
    default: 
         System.out.println("unknown state");
  }
```

Comment: Pay more attention when you copy-paste. You just removed the comment marks, but the word `error` is not part of the Java code.